# Spring batch with paramterized query as input

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Today we have a web app and a legacy API exposing some of REST endpoints to get booking of client. The booking are fetched with a SOAP operation, and the returned response for a specific type of booking differs from the other types. Moreover, these calls are latent and cause a long wait, especially when a client has more than 5 bookings. The next diagram shows a simple interaction between components:

[legacy app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUxBW.png)

The idea of this project is to copy the existent data (clients and booking) in a new schema and get a copy of soap response for each client and booking. The next diagram shows a simple interaction between components with spring batch:

[new app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uslOB.png)

My goal is to use Spring batch to:

- copy client an booking tables
- use the couple booking type/references for each client to call SOPA operations
- persist the result in new booking information table

  ```
  clients = clientRepository.findBy(id)
  foreach client in clients
   bookings = bookingRepository.findBy(id)
   foreach booking in bookings
    call soap with (booking.reference, booking.type)
    map newBooking
    persist newBooking with client.id, booking.reference
  ```

I am new to Spring and I don't know how to do these operations with parameterized query in a repository class and nested with SOAP calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to implement the pseudo code of your solution in Spring Batch is to create a chunk-oriented step defined as follows:

- The item reader reads client IDs
- An item processor fetches bookings for each client
- The item writer writes data to both tables

This pattern has a name, the "driving query pattern", which is documented here: [Common Batch Patterns -> Driving Query Based ItemReaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders).